# Hiding a Secret in Windows Registry

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, windows-vista, registry

I know registry is not a *best* place to hide something.

Right now I'm writing a Licensing software that require to save trial usage information like *first install date* on registry, etc.

What hive in Windows Registry that meet this criteria :

1. Not easily discovered by accident by the Users.
2. The value can be shared among Windows Users.
3. Didn't mess up Windows and Registry Cleaning Utility not consider this value as a garbage.
4. <strike>If can, it work without administrator privileges on Windows Vista and Windows 7</strike>

**Edit : I have excluded items # 4 because it is not possible with item # 2, based on answers from David Heffernan**

Comment: There is no place you can put truly secret data on a user's computer, sorry. Please read: http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/storing-secrets-in-software/

Answer (score 10):

There are no shared locations in the registry that can be written to without admin rights. So your conditions 2 and 4 cannot both be fulfilled. You need to do this with a file I believe.

If you are prepared to drop condition 4 then you need to store it under `HKLM` so that it is shared.  The obvious place is `HKLM\Software\YourCompanyName\YourProductName`. Naturally you would encrypt the data to avoid tampering.  Once you have done that then you don't really care whether or not your users discover it.

Comment: Btw, #4 requirement is optional, but now I know this not possible with #2, thx, :D.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think **HKLM\Software\MyCompanyName\MyProductName** is first place on registry that user search if user want to clear trial data, if they see any crypted value they may decided to delete it.

Comment: If it is deleted then don't run.  Doh.

Comment: If this key don't exist, then my software create new one, and save first install date as current date to this key, I think most of licensing system behave like this.

Comment: @F8R No don't do that. Since you are writing it to `HKLM`, you need admin rights. Make that something you do when you install since that's when you have admin rights.

Comment: It seems I do have to use **admin rights**, because I have to write data in **HKLM** to store *current datetime* every 1 minute, so if users change the OS date to earlier than this value, I can warn user to rollback to recommended date.

Comment: @F8R Nobody will want your program if it requires a UAC elevation every time it is run. Put the information in a file.

Comment: @David Heffernan, yes I have success doing this using file based storage, but I if possible, I want to save the data using registry too. Btw, I will release this library as Open Source at http://flexlx.codeplex.com/ when everything is ready.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to defend against? It sounds like you're putting a lot of effort into "don't let people change their system clock to extend their trial" but none at all into "don't let people edit the Registry key to extend their trial" or "don't let people share Registry keys between machines to turn trials into full keys for free". I actually think those are far more likely. Any software that yelled at me for changing the clock on my own machine would get uninstalled in a hurry.

I recommend you don't try to do this yourself. There are licensing libraries you can use that have thought of the various ways people try to trick software. But if you must, because you want to try it, then take some time to distinguish what happens at install, which might require admin rights, from what happens while you're running and checking, which should not. An app that has to run elevated for no other reason than writing license info to HKLM once a minute would also be uninstalled in a heartbeat from my machine.

So at install, write something obscure/encrypted to a Registry key under HKLM. Make it something that's not super helpful to copy from machine to machine, while you're at it, by combining say a date, an email address, and some other information. At runtime, your code should look partly at the unchanging Registry entry or entries and partly at something else that can change easily, like a file under AppData, an HKCU key, or the current date, to decide whether it's ok for the app to run. (At runtime, if the HKLM key is not there or fails a checksum or whatever, refuse to run and ask for a reinstall. Reinstall can worry about whether the person is trying to get infinite free trials.) Focus on the main ways people try to trick licensing schemes and also on being a usable application. Insisting on elevating or preventing general use of the machine fails on the usability side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I have made clear what I'm trying to do. I was writing Licensing Engine, and what I'm to do is not something taboo in this area, it up to developer that use this Licensing Engine if he/she want to enable this "annoying" feature or not.

Comment: "An app that has to run elevated for no other reason than writing license info to HKLM once a minute would also be uninstalled in a heartbeat from my machine.", this will eliminated more than 50% of commercial software from your computer --kidding :D. Seriously, after Windows Vista generation, we need to get used with this UAC stuff, I once developing simple app that just save and display data from database and it need to run on admin rights, :P

Comment: @F8R no offense, but if your app is not an administrative utility and it needs to run elevated, you're doing it wrong. I refuse to elevate other than to install things, or to do an admin task like regedit. A database query app that needs to elevate? Not happening.

Comment: Yes, it has something to do with database library/connector not in my code, years ago on my Vista, :D.

Answer (score 1):

You can, on install, change permissions of somewhere in HKLM so that all users have write access.

If you choose a place other than HKLM\SOFTWARE\Your Company Name\something than you're being foolish.